# Big string in SQLPlus

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, sqlplus

I need to write a Select query in bind-variable and this query has more than 2500 symbols.

Variable sql_txt clob;

Exec :sql_txt := 'Select .....';

But SQL Plus support only <2499 symbols. 
How to fix it?

Comment: Maybe write all in a text file and execute this file with sqlplus

Answer (score 2):

That limitation is for a single line.

You can break your statement into multiple lines to overcome that limitation, such as:

```
begin
  :sql_txt := 'select ... ' ||
  ' ... ' ||
  ...
  ' ... ';
end;
/
```

Comment: I wrote the same as you. Now I want to print it in SQL Plus, but the text doesn't show, only small part of it.